# django rest patch, how do I save with updated data?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

For a REST PATCH, I want to update some values in the model that already exists and save it back out.  However, I'm obviously missing some step here:

1. Find the item to update
2. Update the the value(s)
3. Save it out

Seems simple enough:

```
def patch( self, request, serialnumber, format = None ):
        try:
            r = Rack.objects.get( serialNumber = serialnumber )
        except Rack.DoesNotExist:
            data = { 'error' : 'item not found' }
            return Response( data, status = status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND )

        s = RackSerializer( r )

        token = "New value for token"

        s.save( token = token, serialNumber = serialnumber )

        data = { 'serialNumber' : serialnumber, 'token' : token }
        return Response( data, status = status.HTTP_200_OK )
```

This gives `"AssertionError: You must call '.is_valid()' before calling '.save().'"`

If I add the s.is_valid() call, I get `"Cannot call '.is_valid()' as no 'data=' keyword argument was passed when instantiating the serializer instance."`

Can someone point me at how to untie this knot?

Comment: can you add the serializer in the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to pass data to the serializer inorder to save it. For that you have to call `is_valid` function before the `save`. And also for partial update, you should add the kwarg `partial=True` in the serializer.

```
def patch( self, request, serialnumber, format = None ):
    try:
        r = Rack.objects.get( serialNumber = serialnumber )
    except Rack.DoesNotExist:
        data = { 'error' : 'item not found' }
        return Response( data, status = status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND )

    token = "New value for token"
    data = { 'serialNumber' : serialnumber, 'token' : token }
    s = RackSerializer(r, data=data, partial=True)
    s.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    s.save()
    return Response( data, status = status.HTTP_200_OK )
```